# SwifType Rate limit exceeded

Tags: elasticsearch, swiftype

I currently have a demo account. I am trying to make a POC using SwifType for my employer. We have a very big database that is indexec every 1h and creates a JSON file. I thought the integration with Elastic would be very easy considering it's only a mater of sending the string when it's generated. I used PHP Curl and got a connection to the API. The code sends out part of the data and then freaks out with a "Rate limit exceeded" error.

How can I manage around that error and get the full JSON indexed?

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
// SENDING DATA TO ELASTIC SEARCH
$arr = array_change_key_case($arr, CASE_LOWER); // Keys to lower case
$arrlist = array_chunk($arr,100); // Split to chunks of 100
foreach($arrlist as $key=>$arr){
    $json = json_encode($arr); // Making the JSON string from the array
    $ch = curl_init('https://host-***.api.swiftype.com/api/as/v1/engines/***/documents');                                                                      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                                                                     
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                                                
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
    $headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer private-***';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $result."<hr>";
}
```

Also, considering this code is going to be indexed every hour, if I am sending the same data over and over, will it UPDATE the previous one or will it duplicate it? If so, how can I manage that?

Comment: There's a [header you can inspect](https://swiftype.com/documentation/site-search/rate_limiting#headers) in order to know where you stands regarding the limit, you should check it, act upon it and back off to make sure you're not crossing that limit.

Comment: What would be the best strategy in order to "backoff"? save where it stopped and continue from there on the next execution? or whait and certain amount of time using sleep() and then continue? Whats the rate limit reset time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look at the `X-RateLimit-Remaining` header (see details [here](https://swiftype.com/documentation/site-search/rate_limiting#headers)) when it hits 0 (or gets close to it) or when you receive a 429 response, you `sleep()` and then retry. I'd recommend using [exponential backoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff) if you receive multiple 429 responses in a row (double the sleep time every time you receive a 429, reset it down to default value when your request succeeds).